# Char object is ignored in string concatenation

Tags: c#, concatenation

I noticed that the fully qualified name of an object I had written was coming back funny. While stepping through my ToString() method, I noticed that when it came to concatenating the string, a character object was consistently being left out of that process.

Here's a step through of what's happening

Before
[image: Before]

After
[image: After]

Where `Char seperator = ':';`

Here's the code of my tostring function:

```
public String ToString(Representaion rep)
        {
            String toReturn = "kuid";
            Char separator = ':';

            switch (rep)
            {
                case Representaion.Colons:
                    break;
                case Representaion.Underscores:
                    separator = '_';
                    break;
                case Representaion.UCROnly:
                    toReturn = userID + ":" + contentID;
                    toReturn += revision == 0 ? "" : ":" + revision;
                    return toReturn;
            }

            toReturn += version == 0 ? "" : version.ToString();
            toReturn += separator + userID + separator + contentID;
            toReturn += revision == 0 ? "" : separator + revision.ToString();
            return toReturn;
        }
```

Where you have

```
private byte version;
private int userID;
private int contentID;
private byte revision;
```

And one case may look like this:

[image]

Already, looking in the locals panel, it seems like VS is getting a string other than what I think it would.

I put in another ToString function to handle a call without parameters (which it does by calling the parametrized function with Representation.Colons):

```
public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.ToString(KUID.Representaion.Colons);
        }
```

Can anyone tell why I'm not getting what I think I should be getting? (Expected result: kuid2:72938:40175:2)

Comment: Must be something you do with it after concatenating. The concatenation is just fine.

Comment: did you hover over `seperator` to check if is actualy ':'

Comment: Are you spelling "separator" incorrectly deliberately, or is that a bug? Ignoring that error: my psychic powers are telling me that you have two different things called `seperator`, and the wrong one is in scope. I suspect the one that is actually in scope is a null string.

Comment: Show us code that we can use to reproduce your issue, otherwise I think we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Edited my post again, with real code samples and a test case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now that you've posted more of your program the problem is obvious. **Char plus int is not string.** Remember,

```
string += char + int + char + int
```

means:

```
string = string + (((char + int ) + char) + int)
```

And when you add an int to a char, you get an int: `'a' + 2` produces the integer character code corresponding to `'c'`, not the string `"a2"`.

You're getting some crazy integer by adding the user id to the colon char.

*Concatenating strings like this is a bad practice* for exactly the reason you have run into. Instead, say:

```
return string.Format("kuid{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}",
    version, separator, userID, separator, contentID, 
    revision == 0 ? "" : separator.ToString(),
    revision == 0 ? "" : revision.ToString());
```

Or, even better, *use a `StringBuilder` object* to build a complicated string.

Incidentally, this illustrates an interesting point about the language:

```
a += b + c;
```

does not mean

```
a = (a + b) + c;
```

It means

```
a = a + (b + c);
```

which as we've seen, might have a different type analysis! Had you said:

```
string = string + char + int + char + int
```

then that would have been analyzed as

```
string = ((((string + char) + int) + char ) + int;
```

Which does make everything a string.

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks Eric. Very good explanation, and I appreciate the various alternatives you gave.

Comment: Boy, I wish this point about `a += b + c` had been documented at places like the [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx](MSDN += operator documentation). Where *is* it documented (besides in your answer above)?

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers The best source for things like this is [the C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx). What you're looking for is the operator precedence table in §7.3.1, where `+=` is in the group with the lowest priority.

Answer (score 1):

I copy pasted your code and it works fine

[image]

Comment: I pasted a few screenshots just now, in a step-by-step fashion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem happens, because the expression to the right is not a string expression. You are working with characters and integers which are not automatically converted to a string, unless they are used within a string expression. You can make it a string expression by starting with a string (here an empty string):

```
toReturn += "" + separator + userID + separator + contentID;
```